# Why does sed 'w' editing command truncate the file instead of appending to it?

Tags: sed

I wrote this shell script.

```
echo a: foo > a.txt
echo a: bar >> a.txt
echo a: baz >> a.txt

sed -i -e '/bar/{ w b.txt' -e 'd }' a.txt
sed -i -e '/baz/{ w b.txt' -e 'd }' a.txt

cat b.txt
```

Here is the output I got.

```
a: baz
```

But I expected this output.

```
a: bar
a: baz
```

I expected this output because http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html says:

```
[2addr]w  wfile
    Append (write) the pattern space to wfile.
```

Since it says "append", I was assuming that the first `sed` command would append `a: bar` to a non-existent file, thus creating that file. Then the second `sed` command would append `a: baz` to the same file.

But the output above shows that this was not the case.

What is wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 2):

You run sed twice, and the first (and only) call to `w` each time truncates the file. To get your expected output, you need to run sed only once:

```
$ sed -i -e '/bar/{ w b.txt' -e 'd }' -e '/baz/{ w b.txt' -e 'd }' a.txt
$ cat b.txt 
a: bar
a: baz
```

Or with less `-e`:

```
sed -i '/bar\|baz/{
    w b.txt
    d
    }' a.txt
```

---

<sub>Alternation with `\|` is a GNU extension to basic regular expressions, just like `-i` is not part of POSIX sed either.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

All write commands of a single sed invocation append to the same file. However, every new invocation truncates the file first.